# TFS Merging Issue with child branch after rollback

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, merge

I have a troubling issue with TFS merging between two branches of my project. Let me try to explain the problem.

1. I have a root branch X
2. I worked on some feature F1 and commited some code to it say C1
3. I recieved a request for another Feature F2 which will be developed in parellel to F1 by another team.
4. I create a child branch of R by the name of Y
5. I rolled back commit C1 from branch X
6. I created yet another branch from X, lets say Z where F2 is being developed.
7. I go on to develop F1 on branch Y and commit some more code to it.
8. Meanwhile F2 is finished and tested on branch Z. We merge F2 from branch Z to branch X.
9. Now F1 has also been tested and is stable. It has to be merged back to Branch X

To do that, I have to first merge X into Y to sync F2 code and then I will have to merge F1 in branch Y back into branch X

But every time I attempt do so, TFS rolls back the changes of commit C1 (Deletes new files added in C1 and undo code in edited files) without even giving me a chance to resolve the conflicts.

I even tried to merge X to Y and manually resolved all the conflicts which took me nearly 2-3 hours as there are many files involved.
But this is happening again when I'm merging back Y to X.
I've been going round and round on this issue for a while now.

Is there a way I can resolve this more easily? Thanks

Comment: You can merge the changeset numbers using cherry pick merge and skip the rollback commit.

Comment: @jessehouwing cherry pick as in selected changesets only right? But wouldn't that still be a problem when I merge back from Y to X, I cannot skip it then, Can I?

Comment: Of course you can, but you'd need to cherry pick merge each of the changesets.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you didn't use the `/keepmergehistory` option when you are doing the roll back.

```
tf rollback /keepmergehistory
```

> This option has an effect only if one or more of the changesets that
>   you are rolling back include a branch or merge change. Specify this
>   option if you want future merges between the same source and the same
>   target to exclude the changes that you are rolling back.
>
> [Source Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/rollback-command-team-foundation-version-control)

You could take a look at the answer from *Isaiah4110* with detail explanation in this question [TFS merge doesn't pick up rollback changeset(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581202/tfs-merge-doesnt-pick-up-rollback-changesets)

For now you could use cherry pick merge each of the changesets as a workaround  like *jessehouwing* suggested.